# Weighting censored outcomes differently in survival analysis

Tags: survival, cox-model

I am conducting survival analysis for an outpatient therapeutic program and building a cox regression model for risk factors. In a normal treatment setting the cure rate should be >85%, <10% Default and <5% death. I am measuring the time-to-event for being cured and censoring defaults, deaths and ongoing cases at the end of the study period.

However, due to extraneous circumstances (war), there is also another treatment outcome category introduced by local authorities, "defaults due to interruption." Standard defaults from treatment are usually due to the individual circumstances of a patient or an unreported death. Defaults due to interruption usually impact all patients across the program at the same time as treatment in the clinical setting is disrupted. Some of these patients are then lost to follow-up or have to re-enroll in treatment and begin it again. When interruptions occur during a treatment period without causing a loss of follow-up or necessitating treatment to be restarted, they are included in the model as a risk factor measured in days of missed treatment. The cure rate in the program is far from normal due to frequent interruptions.

Given the non-standard treatment environment and the relative seriousness of death in the treatment program compared with defaults due to interruption and ongoing cases, what is the best way to weight different outcomes in the regression model.

The cox regression model I have constructed below measures the relative risk factors for being cured but, does not take into account the fact that some censored outcomes like death are much more significant in the treatment setting than ongoing cases and cases that defaulted due to interruptions.

```
modelv1.km<-survfit(Surv(`Days in Treatment - Interuptions`,Outcome=="Cured")~
                  Sex + Displaced + Woreda +`Age at Discharge`+ `Reoccuring Case`+ 
                  `New Admission`+ `Transfer or Readmission`+
                  `Number of Times previously Cured`+ `Number of Times Previously Defaulted`+ `Number of Times Previously Admitted to OTP`+
                  `Communicable (Infectious) Dx`+ `IYCF Counselling Received`+ `Medication Teaching Completed`
                + `Estimated Days of missed treatment`+ `Admission MUAC`+ `Admission Weight (KG)`,
                data=OTPData_V6)
```

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! It seems like this needs to modeled with competing risks of cure and death; see [this vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/compete.pdf) ). "Default due to interruption" might also need to be a competing risk, or perhaps you could model "interruption" as a time-varying covariate, but it's not completely clear to me how that is defined. Could you please edit the question to give details of situations where there would be "default due to interruption"? Please provide information by editing the question; comments are easy to overlook.

Comment: Thank you, that is a good point @EdM

Comment: I have edited the question. "Default due to interruption," is an outcome, specified by the local health office, to account for the fact that, it is not a normal treatment default due to the patients circumstances or poor clinical performance. Periods of interruption are also included as a time-varying covariate when the patient isn't lost to follow up or required to completely restart the treatment. The number of times a patient has previously stopped and then restarted treatment is also included as a risk factor.

Comment: Thank you @EdM, that vignette on multi-state models is exactly what I didn't know that I needed. I think that is enough to get me started so I can figure it out. Much obliged.